# in R, modify date from aug 07, 2020 to 08,07,2020, also how to remove time zone

Tags: r, dataframe

[Fri Aug 07, 2020 05:12 UTC]
I have this date format in a column, how to modify it to be 08, 07,2020 05:12
also, how to remove UTC from all columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `?strptime` for various format options. First convert the data to `POSIXct`, you can then use `format` to get it any format that you want.

```
x <- 'Fri Aug 07, 2020 05:12 UTC'
x1 <- as.POSIXct(x, format = '%a %b %d, %Y %H:%M UTC', tz = 'UTC')
x1
#[1] "2020-08-07 05:12:00 UTC"
format(x1, '%m,%d,%Y %H:%M')
#[1] "08,07,2020 05:12"
```

---

If we want to apply this for multiple columns we can use `lapply`. For example for first 4000 columns where your dataframe is called `df` we can do :

```
cols <- 1:4000
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], function(x) format(as.POSIXct(x, 
              format = '%a %b %d, %Y %H:%M UTC', tz = 'UTC'), '%m,%d,%Y %H:%M'))
```

Comment: it works but how to apply that to all the 4000 columns. all columns are with same annoying format Fri Aug 07, 2020 05:12 UTC

Comment: @nanometer See updated answer to apply this for multiple columns.